# Connection to MS Access 2016 using OLEDB 12

Tags: ms-access, oledb, oledbconnection

I tried connecting to MS Access 2016 database using OLEDB 12 and it worked. However after a few connections(sequential), I noticed that my code got stuck while opening the connection. It would neither fail or exit, just stuck.

I have that that I am properly closing the connection after use.

When I installed Access 2013 runtime and used OLEDB 15, the issue was solved. 
But I am unable to install this runtime on all my nodes in production.

Is there some known issue on using OLEDB 12 to connect to Access 2016. Is it solvable by some code fix ir will I have to move to Access 2013 runtime.